# how to get value against max col?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I've data table like this

```
id, name, timestamp
xx,abc,01-01-2022
x1,abc,01-02-2022
x2,abc,01-03-2022
x3,aby,01-01-2022
x4,aby,01-02-2022
x5,aby,01-03-2022
```

how to get `id` with max `timestamp` and `name is abc` ?

expected output

```
x2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`DENSE_RANK()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_DENSE_RANK.html) window function in such a way like below

```
SELECT id
  FROM (SELECT t.*, DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS dr
          FROM t) tt
 WHERE dr = 1  
   and name = 'abc'
```

where the latest(descendingly sorted timestamp column) values are returned at top.

Comment: its required specific to name = abc